# Export all tables from SQL Server into separate files

Tags: sql-server

I want to extract only table structure from a SQL Server database. But if I extract normally using export wizard only single file is created but I want to create separate files for separate tables.

Could anybody tell me how to do this in SQL Server ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go to Object Explorer, pick `Generate Scripts`:

[image]

Then select what objects to script out, and on the second page of the wizard, select `Single File Per Object`:

[image]

Run the wizard and you have your one file per object as you need it.

Comment: 5 years later and this helped me out a lot! thanks mate!