# Quicker way to export SQL tables into separate pipe-delimited files?

Tags: sql-server

I will need to export the tables in the DB, but into separate files. Instead of running the Export wizard in SQL Server Management Studio for each table, is there a quicker way to accomplish this? The data will need to be in pipe-delimited form. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239825/export-all-tables-from-sql-server-into-separate-files), but it doesn't pull the data, just the table definitions.

Comment: You want to export all tables to CSV files?

Comment: No, to pipe-delimited files, separately one file per table.

Comment: You could probably do this from Powershell

Comment: Sorry that is what I meant. Also how many tables are there?

Comment: SQLChao, ~230 ; dfundako, any leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. You can enable xp_cmdshell

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Then use the undocumented sp_msforeachtable and bcp to export to a file pipe delimited.

```
EXECUTE sp_msForEachTable
  'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''bcp "SELECT * FROM ?" queryout D:\Data\?.txt -t "|" -c -T -S ServerName\InstanceName'''
```

This works and you'll want to make sure you disable xp_cmdshell if it wasn't already enable as it can be exploited (there's plenty to read on this). Also make sure you have permissions to write the files to wherever they need to go.

Comment: @SQLChao, I'm looking through the bcp documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx, is there a parameter option to include column names in the first line of the output files? Thanks.

Comment: No that is a limitation to bcp. A work around is to do something like select 'col1', 'col2', 'col3' etc. UNION and then your select statement.

Comment: @RudyM see my comment. Forgot to tag you in it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using bcp (look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) where you can specify the export format to use pipe for the delimiter. The only drawback is that you will need to specify the table name each time so you will probably need to create a list with the table names and then use a powershell script to loop on the list and execute bcp.

Answer (score 0):

I also found the following which helped, assuming the sp_configure has been set for xp_cmdshell as @SQLChao pointed out in his solution:

```
Execute sp_MSforeachtable
  'Execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''sqlcmd -S DATABASE -E -d mydb -q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT * FROM ?" -W -o C:\TEMP\?.bak -s "|"'''
```

To remove the dashes under column names in the output files:

```
Execute sp_MSforeachtable
  'Execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''findstr /R /C:"^[^-]*$" c:\temp\?.bak > c:\temp\?.txt'''
```

Finally, remove the .bak files created:

```
Execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'del c:\temp\*.bak'
```