# SQL Server: output all column details for all tables into a file

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

Sort of related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359898/quicker-way-to-export-sql-tables-into-separate-pipe-delimited-files):

I would like to output list of all column details for all tables in a SQL Server db. This, using the data from sys.columns. So I started with something like:

```
use mydb
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable
    'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''sqlcmd -S MYPC\SQLEXPRESS -E -d mydb -q "select * from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(?)" -W -o C:\TEMP\?.txt -s"|"'''
```

I have even tried with replacing the where clause with `where object_id = object(''mydb.?'')`

Comment: This command only lists all the columns.

Comment: That's what I would like to output to files; all the sys.columns data for all tables into separate files.

Comment: But you have said "output table schema for all tables" !! Are you going to generate table schema like CREATE TABLE? or you just want to list all columns?

Comment: BTW, what is the problem? do you get any specific error?

Comment: I edited the question detail; I want the table details, i.e., column name, data type, size, maxlength, etc. The issue now is that it doesn't like `object_id(?)` because of the '.'; this is because `?` translates to something like `dbo.mytable` and it would prefer just `object_id(mytable)` without 'dbo.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS instead of SYS.COLUMNS

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_CATALOG,
    TABLE_SCHEMA,
    TABLE_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME,
    DATA_TYPE,
    CHARacter_maximum_length 'Max Length'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
GO
```

There are other columns but those will get you started.

You can also try using osql ([Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)) to run your command from a windows command line.

EX: (Replace MASTER with your database name and specify the query you'd like to use instead of the tables query.

```
osql -E -S . -d MASTER -q "SELECT NAME FROM SYS.TABLES" -o tables.txt
```

**Update 1:**

If you're having trouble removing the schema from the sp_MSforeachtable command try this:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where 
table_name = REPLACE(REPLACE(''?'',''[dbo].['',''''),'']'','''')'
```

That will give you just the table name without the [dbo]. and the trailing bracket.

**Update 2:**

If you wanted to use the object_id instead you could try this:

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'select * from sys.columns
where object_id = (SELECT OBJECT_ID(''?''))'
```

Comment: Thanks @jjoiner. MSforeachtable selects all tables as 'dbo.tablename'. So when I run a command like `select * from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(?)` , it complains about not finding a multi-part identifier. I think object_id would expect only the table name, not the multi-part identifier. I've even tried something ridiculous like a replace(?,'dbo.',''). And thanks for the suggestion to use osql.

Comment: I updated the answer @RudyM to include one way to remove the schema from your command.

Comment: Try object_id = (SELECT OBJECT_ID(''?''))' @RudyM

Comment: Thanks @jjoiner, but it still complains about dbo. I stripped it down to a simple select for the same result:    
use dbtest
    EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable
        'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
        ''osql -E -S "MYPC\SQLEXPRESS" -d "DBTEST" -q "(SELECT OBJECT_ID(''?''))" '''

Comment: thanks again. Turns out I had to add extra single quotes: `select * from sys.column where object_id = object_id(''''?'''')`

Comment: I think you just have an extra quote in there somewhere. This works for me. 

EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable 'EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''osql -E -S MYSERVER -d MYDATABASE -q ''select name from sys.columns where object_id = (SELECT OBJECT_ID(''?''))'